# Usings tikz, how can I specify a coordinate with the x value from the coordinate in one system and the y value from the coordinate in another system?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Usually, I would use `(a, b |- c, d)` to get the coordinate `(a, d)`. But what do I do when `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` are in different coordinate systems? In particular, my first coordinate is `(axis cs:a, b)` (from `pgfplots`) and the second coordinate is simply `(c, d)`. In addition, I'm using symbolic x coordinates, so `a` is specified as `{foobar}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={{foo}, {bar}}]

\addplot [] coordinates {
    ({foo}, 0)
    ({bar}, 0)
};

% Works fine:
\draw [->, green] (axis cs:{foo}, 0.1) -- (axis cs:{bar}, 0.1);

% Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input ' 0 |- 0' as a floating point
%  number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '|- 0'..
\draw [->, red] (axis cs:{foo}, 0 |- 0, -0.1) -- (axis cs:{bar}, 0 |- 0, -0.1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use braces to group the coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={{foo}, {bar}}]

\addplot [] coordinates {
    ({foo}, 0)
    ({bar}, 0)
};

% Works fine:
\draw [->, green] (axis cs:{foo}, 0.1) -- (axis cs:{bar}, 0.1);

\draw [->, red] ({axis cs:{foo}, 0} |- 0, -0.1) -- ({axis cs:{bar}, 0} |- 0, -0.1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```